# Google Apps Script: How to find a listItem object in a google document and insert a item to it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Following the [documentation sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item), I'm trying to create a function that searchs for a numerated list in a google document and, if finds it, adds a new item to that list. But I get this error: `Cannot find method setListId(string). (line 21, file "test")` or, if I change line 21 content (replacing `elementContent`for `newElement`), I get the message: `Preparing for execution...` and nothing happens. How to fix it?

This is my code:

```
function test() {
  var elementContent = "New item testing"; // a paragraph with its formating
  var targetDocId = "1R2c3vo9oOOjjlDR_n5L6Tf9yb-luzt4IxpHwwZoTeLE";  
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocId);
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();
  for (var i = 0; i < targetDoc.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = targetDoc.getChild(i);
    if (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
        var listId = child.getListId();
        var newElement = body.appendListItem(elementContent);
        newElement.setListId(newElement);
        Logger.log("child = " + child);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have created an endless loop, this message is typical of an endless loop, it will probably also return "DocumentApp service not available" so wait a bit and try to log the results without inserting new data to see what happens. (I don't have time right now to test further)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, I tried to play with your script to see what happened and I came up with that code below...

I'm not saying it solves your issue and/or is the best way to achieve what you want but at least it gives a result that works as expected.

Please consider it as a "new playground" and keep experimenting on it to make it better ;-)

```
function test() {
  var elementContent = "New item testing"; // a paragraph with its formating
  var targetDocId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();  
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocId);
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();
  var childIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < targetDoc.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = targetDoc.getChild(i);
    if (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      while(child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
        child = targetDoc.getChild(i)
        childIndex = body.getChildIndex(child);
        Logger.log(childIndex)
        i++
      }
      child = targetDoc.getChild(i-2)
      var listId = child.getListId();
      Logger.log(childIndex)
      var newElement = child.getParent().insertListItem(childIndex, elementContent);
      newElement.setListId(child);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine! I just adapted the end lines to avoid and empty item (my template always start with an empty element) adding this `if (child.getText() == '') { childIndex = childIndex -1;}` and this line: `var lastEmptyItem = targetDoc.getChild(childIndex +1).removeFromParent();` . Thanks, I'll be waiting for your 2014 projects (A GAS for Dummies, I hope). It also would be a great resource for deliberate pratice if someone with your knowledge could give google helpouts on GAS.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble on insert a paragraph ("a detached, deep copy of the current element") instead of a string as itemList. I'll create another question.