# How to copy ListItems from one Google Document to another while preserving numbering?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

The accepted answer to [How to copy content and formatting between Google Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987101/how-to-copy-content-and-formatting-between-google-docs) indicates that we have to add conditional code just to copy elements. But I cannot get it to work for ListItem types, because the target document shows the list items without the original numbering.

```js
var source_doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var selection = source_doc.getSelection();
if (!selection) {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('Please make a selection first.');
    return;
}

var target_doc = DocumentApp.create('CopyOf'+DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName());
var target_body = target_doc.getBody();

var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var source_element = elements[i].getElement();
    var copy_element = source_element.copy();
    if (copy_element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        target_body.appendParagraph(copy_element);
    } else if (copy_element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        // This does not keep the numbering on the list item. Why?
        target_body.appendListItem(copy_element);

        // And playing games with setListId doesn't work either:
        // copy_element.setListId(source_element);
        // target_body.appendListItem(copy_element);
    }
    // TODO: Handle the other elements here.
}
```

The source document displays like this:

[image: source document]

Target document renders like this:

[image: bad rendering]

How do I preserve ListItem formatting?

This seems much much harder than it should be: What I really want is to copy the users selection verbatim into a new document preserving all formatting, and from a google script.

It would seem that this could be done at a higher level.  I can manually copy and paste and preserve the formatting, just not from the script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the cause of this is that there's a problem with using a `Selection`. Reading from a document directly seems to work fine.

Try appending the `ListItem` as text as a workaround.

```
target_body.appendListItem(copy_element.getText());
```

This will only copy the text though, not the formatting. You can also try to implement it by making a new list instead of copying the element directly. Here's a sample [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714741/google-apps-script-how-to-find-a-listitem-object-in-a-google-document-and-inser) that might help.

Comment: I'm actually looking to do this from a higher level. The explicit checks for types of elements is not to my liking and is not going to be maintainable. I considered a rather unpleasant approach: Just copying the entire document to the destination and then removing the things that are not required (which is equally problematic). +1 but not really the answer I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem (but not using a selection). It was being copied as a list but without any actual bullets. I just re-set the bullets manually like this:

```
target_body.appendListItem(copy_element).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER)
```